# "cologne" and "aftershave" for "fragrance for men"

Tags: american-english, word-usage, british-english, vernacular, gender-positive

Per [Farlex Trivia Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perfume),  *perfume* or *parfum* is 20–40% oil and the highest concentration; *eau de toilette* is 10–18% oil, and *cologne* or *eau de cologne* is 3–9% oil.

Leaving aside the technical aspect of those terms, does the meaning of "aftershave" and "cologne" overlap in common usage with that of any kind of fragrance for men, whatever the concentration level of perfume?

To put it differently, is **John Doe** more prone to refer (colloquially) to his fragrance as *aftershave* or *cologne* rather than *perfume*, because the latter might have strong gender connotations to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The truth is that fragrances for men, in fact what is standardly classified as *eau de parfum* by the concentration of aromatic oils ([Wikipedia on fragrance types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eau_de_toilette#Types)) are **marketed as cologne**. Look at [www.perfume.com](http://www.perfume.com/) or [www.fragrancenet.com](http://www.fragrancenet.com/): both categorize fragrances into **women's perfume** and **men's cologne** (for perfectly analogous products).

Why? Apparently largely for reasons suspected by OP: to avoid the word *perfume*. [This informed article](http://www.artofmanliness.com/2015/10/14/guide-to-fragrance/) is quite explicit:

> **Cologne** *(Eau de cologne)*. Oldest term for perfume, used in North America for masculine scents. [...]

The paper [Gendered adverts: an analysis of female and male images in contemporary perfume ads](http://revistacomsoc.pt/index.php/comsoc/article/download/702/623) by Sandra Tuna and Elsa Freitas has this to say:

> Male perfume adverts have evolved in a different way, especially because this
>   kind of product, and its advertising, was for some time considered as mostly feminine.
>   Thus, in the 1960s and 1970s, alternatives to the word ‘perfume’ (eau de toilette,
>   cologne and aftershave) were preferred, so as to avoid feminine connotations, a concern
>   that was also patent in the projection of blatant masculinity (Classen et al., 1994:
>   190-191). The idea that perfume adverts would make men more attractive to women
>   continued to be exploited, and, according to the authors, contemporary adverts have
>   become more sophisticated, but they still avoid the traditional connotations of the
>   term ‘perfume’, and still highlight the image of masculinity, which is now combined
>   with an idea of sensitivity.

Little wonder then if John Doe says *cologne* where Jane would speak of *perfume*.

As a side remark, my impression is that girls usually stick to the terminology provided by Wikipedia, and are particular about what product (in what concentration) they are exactly getting for their money. As remarked by Benjamin Harman, the same scent can come in a variety of products, from an *extract* down to a body milk, which may be viewed by some as a convenient way of adjusting the olfactory facet of their personality to a situation, or achieving a nonchallant layering effect for their scent.

Answer (score 8):

No, aftershave and cologne are most definitely *not* the same thing.  You will find at any beauty counter or perfume section of any department store that a men's fragrance, like *Code* by Armani or *Polo* by Ralph Lauren, is sold as a cologne *and* as an aftershave.  They are two separate products, two entirely different things.

The aftershave of a fragrance is much less expensive than the cologne.  It has a much higher alcohol content and has an opening in the top of the bottle that allows a man to pour it into his hands and splash it onto his face after shaving.  A bottle of Armani Code aftershave costs between $10 and $15.

The cologne of a fragrance costs many times that of the aftershave, is much more highly concentrated, and comes in a bottle that usually has an atomizer at the top that allows it to be sprayed on sparingly.  A bottle of Armani Code cologne costs about $100 for fewer ounces than the $10 to $15 bottle of aftershave.

If you buy a gift set of a men's fragrance, you will find that it normally contains, among other things, a bottle that is marked cologne and a different bottle that is marked aftershave.  The cologne is the pricey item in that set.  The cost of a fragrance's cologne's is usually six or seven times that of its aftershave.  An aftershave is merely a relatively inexpensive accessory to a cologne, much like a soap or a deodorant in that same scent.

Comment: Just to add a little more - aftershave is literally for after shaving - shaving opens up the pores, the alcohol in aftershave closes the pores. As Benjamin said, to use aftershave, you pour it into your hands, then basically cover your neck/face with it, thus closing all of your pores (and it stings quite a bit, see the Home Alone aftershave clip). Aftershave need not smell like rubbing alcohol, though, and can be given a fragrance. Cologne, on the other hand, is "pure fragrance", and serves only the purpose of making you smell nice - you do not slather it onto your skin like aftershave.

Comment: @Jake: "you do not slather it onto your skin like aftershave" - unfortunately, there are quite a few men out there who failed to learn this tidbit. (Hint: if I can smell you coming before I can see you coming, there's something wrong.)

Comment: @Marthaª and to make matters worse, a man would potentially know not to slather on expensive cologne because they've paid so much for it that they'd probably try to conserve it (barring it being a present or something). That means that the worst slather offenders are probably using cheap cologne...and a lot of it.

Answer (score 4):

Another answer already elegantly discusses cologne versus aftershave, so I am focusing on the gender difference.  As this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=perfume%20for%20men%20%2B%20men%27s%20perfume%2C%20perfume%20for%20women%20%2B%20women%27s%20perfume%2C%20cologne%20for%20men%20%2B%20men%27s%20cologne%2C%20cologne%20for%20women%20%2B%20women%27s%20cologne&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28perfume%20for%20men%20%2B%20men%20%27s%20perfume%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28perfume%20for%20women%20%2B%20women%20%27s%20perfume%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28cologne%20for%20men%20%2B%20men%20%27s%20cologne%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28cologne%20for%20women%20%2B%20women%20%27s%20cologne%29%3B%2Cc0) shows, there is a clear preference for cologne <=> men and perfume <=> women, however the opposite is not unheard of.

[image]

Note that the distinctions have become more pronounced recently, and were almost reversed in the 1940s.  I can't explain the explosion for the (men's cologne + cologne for men) curve since 1970.

Comment: I can so see a gender-enlightened, metro-sexual America having men embrace the word "perfume" or "parfume." It should be noted though that, like aftershave is different than cologne, cologne is different than perfume. Aside from the nature of the scent, women's cologne is very much like men's cologne: the same basic water- and alcohol-based composition. Women's perfume, on the other hand, is even more concentrated than cologne, much more, and it's oil-based without an atomizer. Women touch the open top to a finger and dab it behind their ears, or against a wrist and rub their wrists together.

Comment: Then there is the transsexual fabric softener sheet or laundry detergent perfume. Fortunately for ngram, sales of the former at least are declining: https://www.wsj.com/articles/fabric-softener-sales-are-losing-their-bounce-1481889602